# Difference b/w primary and autowire-candidate attribute of bean tag in spring

Tags: spring, autowired

I am new to spring. When i am going through auto wiring byType i came to know about these attributes primary and autowire-candidate.

I didn't get the exact difference b/w these two as setting these parameter to false will make the other bean a candidate for autowiring.

Can anybody help me in understanding these two.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say there is interface

```
interface Translator { String translate(String word);}
```

Your application use the translator widely to translate from English to Polish. However, is some specific case you want to use dedicated translator, because vocabulary is specific. For example, string always means "sequence of characters" but never "underwear".

Sample configuration:

```
<bean class="EnglishToPolishTranslator" />
<bean class="ComputerScienceEnglishToPolishTranslator" autowire-candidate="false"/>
```

Everywhere `EnglishToPolishTranslator` will be autowired except  some concrete place where `ComputerScienceEnglishToPolishTranslator` will be injected by reference.

Some day next customer arrive with requirement: use simpler words. The requirement is achieved by class `SimpleEnglishToPolishTranslator`. But computer science translator should remain unchanged: it is too costly to modify it.

Your company want keep product easy to maintain. Base application will not be modified, but for the customer the product will extended with extra library configured:

```
<bean class="SimpleEnglishToPolishTranslator" primary="true"/>
```

In result, everywhere `SimpleEnglishToPolishTranslator` will be used except computer science area.

Maybe it is overcomplicated, but shows a difference I found between autowire-candidate and primary

BTW, "autowire-candidate" doesn't have corresponding annotation. It looks to me that "autowire-candidate" is dead end in Spring evolution

Answer (score 2):

if we configure bean for more than one time with different ids then IOC will throw an Exception. To overcome this duplicate beans problem, we can use `autowire-candidate=”false”` or `primanry="true"`

Example: i have two classes Mobile and Processor

Case -1:  `autowire-candidate=”false”`

```
<bean id="mobile" class="com.Mobile" autowire="byType">
    <property name="mobileName" value="Redmi"></property>
    <property name="mobileModel" value="Note 5"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="process1" class="com.Processor" 
autowire-candidate="false">
    <property name="process" value="2GHz"></property>
    <property name="ram" value="4GB"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="process2" class="com.Processor">

    <property name="process" value="1GHz"></property>
    <property name="ram" value="3GB"></property>
</bean>
```

As per above configuration, process1 bean will be ignored and process2 bean will be injected.

Case -2:  `primanry="true"`

```
<bean id="mobile" class="com.Mobile" autowire="byType">
    <property name="mobileName" value="Redmi"></property>
    <property name="mobileModel" value="Note 5"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="process1" class="com.Processor" primary="true">
    <property name="process" value="2GHz"></property>
    <property name="ram" value="4GB"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="process2" class="com.Processor">

    <property name="process" value="1GHz"></property>
    <property name="ram" value="3GB"></property>
</bean>
```

As per above configuration, process2 bean will be ignored and process1 bean will be injected.